# Clean way of selecting drawable from a list of bitmaps at runtime?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

So I've got a list of country ISO codes ("US", "UK", "AU"...) and I want to use a different drawable depending on the ISO code I'm given. Right now my solution is that of using a big switch statement

```
switch(iso){
    case "AU":
    icon = R.drawable.al_au;
etc...
```

This seems unwieldy and bad practice-ish. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? The only other thought I had would be to form the drawable names from the iso codes and use reflection but I believe that would be awfully inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your drawables can follow a naming convention then you can do something like

To get the `Drawable` object itself:

```
iconDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                   getResouces().getIdentifier("al_" + iso.toLowerCase(),
                                        "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

To get just the `Drawable` identifier:

```
icon = getResouces().getIdentifier(
           "al_" + iso.toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a hacky-hacky thing :) As long as you can provide a sorted list of consecutive names, you can just add an index of an item to the first item.

```
icon = R.drawable.al_au + Arrays.asList("AU","PL","US").indexOf(iso);
```

Comment: Although I won't use this solution in my project I appreciate the thought :P but at least it's better than my switch statement!